# Can an AD DS user be replicated/synched to AD LDS into a different container/organisational unit?

Tags: active-directory, ad-lds

Have some **data in the form of attributes** to be shared on the directory attached to users and <strike>groups</strike> containers/OU or group policy.

The current AD DS has OU and container groupings of users which doesn't match the way this data should be applied, so we want to apply a different grouping <strike>without using Group Policy and groups</strike>.

It has been decided by others (we are yet to persuade otherwise) that the data should also not be on the main AD DS.

So hope is to create AD LDS with a subset of users from AD DS and maintain them in a different OU/container structure.

Is this possible?

**Edit: Background**

Some administrators don't like to change their AD schema to add new attributes, or just want to manage certain application data as separate entity from the main directory.

These same admin had an LDAP datastore separate to AD, not synched containing the app data.
In the LDAP datastpre they had a per department (multiple departments) structure of

Department
Department/Testers
Department/Admin

So that Admin and Testers got the default attributes applied to all users + some extra settings or overridden settings.

In the AD DS this structure isn't present.

They now wish to remove this LDAP datastore (reasons unexplainable) and use ADAM or ADLDS instead.  They don't seem to know ADAM/ADLDS and want to know how to migrate with as little effort as possible the data on containers/OU and users from the LDAP to the AD AM/LDS keeping the same settings for each user.  I have no idea on what tools they have available already or what they might use to make this replicate/synch nicely.

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't make security groups as you want them, and assign the permissions to the groups?

Comment: What mfinni said

Comment: We could make security groups, I'm not familiar with how to apply attributes to a security group directly, does AD LDS support Group Policy on security groups as AD DS does?

Comment: I think you need to more-fully explain the problem you're solving and the desired end-state, from a user perspective, because as stated (and edited) I find your question weird and confusing.

Comment: Unfortunately I am trying to work out with insufficient knowledge and some preset boundaries which may not make sense in a perfect world but I can't change.  So yes, wierd and confusing sorry.